# Retrieve specific field of a related list as field of its parent

Tags: lookup, related-list

I´m trying to figure out how to achieve the following requirement:

> Pick a specific field from a related list of Account and put in in a field in Account object. Like the image below.

[image]

This would help us to segment our campaign and give us at a glance the type of products the company has acquired, like summarized data.

Solution path would be: Trigger? Process Builder? Workflow rule? Junction Object? How?

Comment: The language you've used in your question suggests that this would be best accomplished as a report. Is there a reason why you can't do this as a report?

Comment: Hi @DerekF thanks for asking! Yes, actually I would have to run 2 different reports, and then cross-reference both externally, using excel for example.

Comment: check out Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries - http://andyinthecloud.com/2015/02/16/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries-tool-dlrs-spring15-release/ (free)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought was that this could be accomplished with a report using a report type of `Accounts with <relatedObject>`. With the information that you've provided, I can't see how this wouldn't work (With such a report, you would be able to see the individual Accounts, and all product models available on each individual Account.)

That aside, assuming that a report is not a viable solution, my next thought would be to do this with a Trigger.

**+edit:**

As I was writing this, crop1645 commented about the [declarative rollup summaries](http://andyinthecloud.com/2015/02/16/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries-tool-dlrs-spring15-release/) package. I had completely forgotten about this, and it's probably the best solution (after building a report).

I'll keep going in case someone can't use the delcarative rollup summary package.

**/edit**

You could go about this in two ways, (spoiler: they end up being very similar) depending on the type of relationship between `Account` and your unnamed `relatedObject`. For ease, I'll assume your related object is called `Product__c`, and that it's relationship name is simply `Products`

**If your two objects are in a Master-Detail Relationship**

This is the easy case. Assuming `Account` is the Master object, you could use a Parent-Child subquery in an Account Trigger `Before Update`.

```
Set<String> models; = new Set<String>();
Account temp;
for(Account acct : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Model__c FROM Products) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]){
    temp = Trigger.newMap.get(acct.Id);
    models = new Set<String>();
    for(Product__c prod : acct.get('Products')){
        models.add(prod.Model__c);
    }
    temp.All_Available_Products__c = String.join(new List<String>(models), '; ');
}
```

In the above example, the `temp` variable is needed because to take advantage of the ability of the `Before Update` trigger event to update the `Account` record without DML, you need to update the instance of the `Account` record that resides within `Trigger.new` or `Trigger.newMap`.

The `Set<String> models` is just there to make sure that you don't end up with duplicate models being listed on your Account.

The Master-Detail relationship ensures that Account's trigger(s) will be fired when a `Product__c` is inserted or updated.

**If your Product__c object has a lookup relationship to Account**

You can largely reuse the code that was used for the Master-Detail case. The difference being that you have to gather a list of Account Ids instead of being able to rely on a Trigger context variable, and you need to perform a DML update.

```
// Gather all of the Ids of accounts that your Product__c records are related to
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Product__c prod : Trigger.new){
    accountIds.add(prod.Account__c);
}

// At this point, most of the rest of the work can be done by code very similar to the code used in the previous example
Set<String> models; = new Set<String>();
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
for(Account acct : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Model__c FROM Products) FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]){
    models = new Set<String>();
    for(Product__c prod : acct.get('Products')){
        models.add(prod.Model__c);
    }
    // Note that we're not using the 'Account temp' variable here
    acct.All_Available_Products__c = String.join(new List<String>(models), '; ');
    // Because we're not in an Account Trigger (Before Update), we need to add the modified account to a list so we can call DML update
    accountsToUpdate.add(acct);
}

update accountsToUpdate;
```

Comment: *@Derek F* and *crop1645*, I´ve seen your comments right now. I will try both solutions and I will get back to you with my comments ok? In the meantime, I really appreciate your time helping me on that !!!!!!! Both genius! Give me a day to write here again...